# Samba, shared folders and windows 8

Tags: samba

I've Ubuntu 13.10 and another pc with windows8. I use an external drive on Ubuntu and tried to share it to have access on Windows8. I've installed Samba. The problem in on windows side. I can see the share folders on Ubuntu but one I double click it says that windows can't access to Ubuntu. If I try to map a folder, I log on with the user setted on Samba , it trys to establish the connections and then reports an error saying that the speciefied folder is using another user and password. 
I also did another test that was to create a folder on the Ubuntu desktop and share it and on windows I can access to this folder with any problem. Also I tried to share the external drive from properties (like i did it in the other folder) but without success.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Please Open `/etc/samba/smb.cnf` and Cross check

- workgroup name
- authentication
- netlogon

and in [shareddrive] block

browsable = yes

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide